# "replset couldn't find a slave with id 1, not tracking 53327c7cb143ca63cef31087"

Tags: mongodb, replication

After frequent rs.add / rs.remove, "replset couldn't find a slave with id 1, not tracking 53327c7cb143ca63cef31087" appear in the mongod.log.  Can it be safely ignored ?  or Does it imply a issue behind ?

Answer (score 0):

After rs.add / rs.remove, your replica _id may not follow a continuous order of number, e.g.:

```
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
         {
            "_id" : 4,
            "host" : "mongodb0.example.net:27017"
         },
         {
            "_id" : 5,
            "host" : "mongodb1.example.net:27017"
         },
         {
            "_id" : 7,
            "host" : "mongodb2.example.net:27017"
         }
     ]
}
```

You can use [rs.reconfig()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/) to re-etablish the order:

```
var cfg = {
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
         {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongodb0.example.net:27017"
         },
         {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongodb1.example.net:27017"
         },
         {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongodb2.example.net:27017"
         }
     ]
}
rs.reconfig(cfg);
```

This log error message can be safely ignored as long as you don't have any issue with your read queries (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1260)